# Making a css toggle with radio buttons (using Foundation 4 )

Tags: radio-button, zurb-foundation

I'm having this totally silly problem in a custom Foundation 4 form.

What I'm trying to to is a pure CSS toggle where you can switch between "sale" and "rent". They need to be `radio buttons` but I don't want them to look like that, so I'm trying to follow [this example](http://www.onextrapixel.com/2013/07/31/creating-content-tabs-with-pure-css/) to style them by hiding the `inputs` and making the `labels` look as simple `links`.

The markup is like this:

```html
<form class="custom">
    <input type="radio" name="switchRadio" id="sale" value="sale" checked="" class="no-custom">
    <label for="sale">Sale</label>
    <input type="radio" name="switchRadio" id="rent" value="rent" class="no-custom">
    <label for="rent">Rent</label>
    <!--more form elements-->
</form>
```

I know that default markup for custom forms in Foundation is to have the `input` nested inside of the label but I can't do it that way because I can't target a checked `input` parent with CSS, but I can target its sibling.

I've added the `no-custom` class because, as inputs are not visible, I don't need them to be pretty.

So for some weird reason, the `label for="sale"` works fine, clicking the label checks the `input id="sale"`, but clicking the `label for="rent"` also checks the `input id="sale"`. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I've found out that Foundation alters the normal behaviour of `labels` via javascript. If I disable my javascript, `radio buttons` and their `labels` work just fine.

So i followed the recommended markup, nesting `inputs` inside `labels` and added a `span` tag that is sibling to the `input`, and styled the `span` instead of the label. I keep the 'no-custom' classes because I don't need custom styles for those inputs.

So in the end it looks like this:

```html
<form class="custom">
    <label for="sale">
        <input type="radio" name="switchRadio" id="sale" value="sale" checked=""  class="no-custom">
        <span>Rent</span>
    </label>
    <label for="rent">
        <input type="radio" name="switchRadio" id="rent" value="rent" class="no-custom">
        <span>Sale</span>
    </label>
</form>
```

And the CSS in case someone's interested:

```
input[type=radio] {
    display: none
}
input:checked + span {
    //your styles for the span next to the checked radio
}
```

So simple and it had me mad for a while!